# Unit issues with commutator relations with two dependent variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, units, dirac-delta-distributions

Suppose I have the following commutator relation for an operator $a[x,\omega]$ which depends on position $x$ and frequency $\omega$

$$
\left[a[x,\omega],a^{\dagger}[x^{\prime},\omega^{\prime}]\right]=\delta(x-x^{\prime})\delta(\omega-\omega^{\prime}).
$$

This is an unequal position and unequal frequency commutator. Based on the two Dirac delta functions, the unit for $a[x,\omega]$ must be
$$
\text{Dim}[a[x,\omega]] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{length}\times\text{frequency}}}.
$$

Suppose now that the position is fixed, namely, I'm looking at an equal-space commutator. Hence $x=x^{\prime}$ and the commutator simplifies to
$$
\left[a[x,\omega],a^{\dagger}[x,\omega^{\prime}]\right]=\delta(x-x)\delta(\omega-\omega^{\prime})=\delta(0)\delta(\omega-\omega^{\prime}) =\delta(\omega-\omega^{\prime}),
$$
where now, the unit of $a[x,\omega]$ becomes $1/\sqrt{\text{frequency}}$.

My question is, how is this possible? Surely fixing the position can't possibly change the dimension of the operator? What am I missing here and what are some good resources to read up on something like this?

**Edit:** Another analogy that I can think of are simply the raising and lowering operators of the harmonic oscillator. In general, they are time-dependent (but dimensionless) such that
$$
[a(t),a^{\dagger}(t)]=1.
$$
But it is possible for them to be evaluated at unequal times. In which case
$$
[a(t),a^{\dagger}(t^{\prime})]=\delta(t-t^{\prime})
$$
However, the Dirac delta here implies that the unit of $a(t)$ must be $1/\sqrt{\text{time}}$. How can this be?

**Edit 2:** I noticed I wrote $\delta(0) = 1$ which is clearly not true. I think I meant to say $\int\delta(0)dx = 1$. This suggests that some integration might be involved in making the dimensions consistent when fixing one of the variables.

Comment: What is $\delta(0)$...?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I see your point. $\delta (0)$ should be infinity. I think I just confused Kronecker delta with Dirac delta. In either case, what is the correct way of approaching the collapse of the delta function of one variable?

Comment: The correct way is to not approach it at all. The delta function is not a true function, and evaluating it at specific points will lead to trouble.